# Где ошибка в форме обратной связи?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

На странице выводится две формы обратной связи. Первая работает корректно, вторая не работает. В чем может быть ошибка? И еще один момент: при нажатии на кнопку "отправить" скрипт уведомляет, что письмо отправлено. Но письмо на почту не поступает. Где-то есть ошибка? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Благодарю!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#feedback_submit").click(function(){ 
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"sendmail.php",
        data:$("#callbacks").serialize(),
        error:function(){$("#erconts").html("Произошла ошибка!");},
  beforeSend: function() {
            $("#erconts").html("Отправляем данные...");
        },
  success: function(result){
   $("#erconts").html(result);
   checkThis();
  }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

```html
<form name="MyForm" action="" id="callbacks" class="feedback_form" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="name" data-placeholder="true" placeholder="Как к вам обращаться?" required>
     <input type="text" name="email" data-placeholder="true" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
     <input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="feedback_submit">
    </form>
    <div id="erconts"></div>
        
<form name="MyForm" action="" id="callbacks" class="feedback_form" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="name" data-placeholder="true" placeholder="Как к вам обращаться?" required>
     <input type="text" name="email" data-placeholder="true" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
     <input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="feedback_submit">
    </form>
    <div id="erconts"></div>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["email"])){
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {$name = $_POST["name"];}
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {$email = $_POST["email"];}

if($name=="" or $email==""){
    echo "Заполните, пожалуйста, все поля!";
}else{
    $ip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$to = "pochta@mail.ru";
$subject = "Заявка!";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
";
$headers .= "From: Заявка с сайта";
$message = "
Имя: $name<br>
E-mail: $email<br><br>

--------------------------------------------------------<br>
---------------IP отправителя: $ip<br>
"; 
$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


 if ($send == "true")
 {
 echo "Поздравляем! Ваша заявка принята!";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Не удалось отправить, попробуйте снова!";
 }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем html повторяются `id` элементов. Выборка по `id` -  `$("#...")` - характерна тем, что возвращает обертку из набора элементов числом не более одного. Отсюда и проблемы.

Обычно в таких случаях `id` меняют на `class`.